# Как рассчитать количество комбинаций md5 хеша?

Tags: алгоритм, md5

Правильно ли я понимаю что буквы в хеше могут быть только abcdef и количество комбинаций будет равно 16 в 32 степени?

Comment: Да. . . . . . .

Comment: вообще то что вы называете md5 - это ее человекочитаемое представление в 16-ричной форме. сам по себе хеш это просто набор из 16 байт, т.е. 128 бит, т.е. вариантов 2 в 128 степени, что конечно равно 16 в 32

Comment: Только наверно это теоретический предел - никто ведь не перебирал все возможные варианты. Вполне возможно, что существует какое то 128 битное число, которое никогда не будет сгенерировано функцией md5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .. буквы в хеше могут быть только abcdef

Да. Плюс 10 цифр. Итого 16 символов (на то она и 16-ти-ричная система счисления). А 16 вариантов дают 4 бита `(2^4=16)`.

Символов 32, т.е. 32 4-х битных символа, итого `32 * 4 = 128` бит.

Один бит принимает 2 значения: нолик или единицу. Для 128-битного двоичного числа число вариантов будет равно `2^128 ~ 3,402823669E38`. Т.е. число в котором 39 знаков :)